# How to align minor ticks separately from major ticks with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

In the MWE below, I would like to have the major ticks center-aligned and the minor ticks on the x axis to be inner-aligned, but as best as I can tell from the manual, all `tick align` commands apply to both major and minor ticks. How can I create something functionally equivalent to a (nonexistent) `xminortick align=inside`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        align=center,
        title={Sample Graph},
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis line style={-Latex,shorten >=-10pt},
        ylabel={Height $h$},
        xlabel={Time $t$ (ms)},
        tick style={solid,black},
        major tick length=8pt,
        minor tick length=4pt,
        % If the next key existed, that would be the behavior I'm after
        %xminortick align=inside,
        xmin=0, xmax=500,   
        xtick distance=100,
        ymin=0, ymax=15,
        ytick distance=5,
        minor x tick num=4,
        ]
    \addplot[thick,domain=0:500] {-3*(x-500)*x/12500};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current behavior (all ticks center-aligned):

[image: MWE output of sample graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{%
    every minor tick/.append style={yshift=2pt}, 
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        align=center,
        title={Sample Graph},
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis line style={-Latex,shorten >=-10pt},
        ylabel={Height $h$},
        xlabel={Time $t$ (ms)},
        tick style={solid,black},
        major tick length=8pt,
        minor tick length=4pt,
        % If the next key existed, that would be the behavior I'm after
        %xminortick align=inside,
        xmin=0, xmax=500,   
        xtick distance=100,
        ymin=0, ymax=15,
        ytick distance=5,
        minor x tick num=4,
        ]
    \addplot[thick,domain=0:500] {-3*(x-500)*x/12500};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm kicking myself for forgetting yshift. Thanks.

Comment: I must say that I am not 100% happy with this, but all my attempts to change the alignment of the minor ticks failed (even though they do not produce errors).